# How do I create hardlinks in a destination directory to each file in a source directory, using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hardlink

I've tried using the New-Item cmdlet with -ItemType Hardlink but I haven't succeeded in getting the right parameters (whether -Name, -Path, -Value, -Target).  I've tried piping the source files to New-Item using gci but that hasn't worked either.  I know I can use mklink or other utilities but I'd like to know how this could be done in Powershell.

Comment: Are you sure you are following the help file's guidance/examples, or are you just pointing around to try and figure it out?   ;-} We've all done it in our careers at one point or the other. It would be best if you showed your code and error messages for us to have other needed detail to assist. Sometimes old school, even in the PS console may be most prudent.

Comment: You are very right!  I was just impatiently trying to make it work, and didn't think it out like I should have.

Answer (score 1):

So, are you saying a simple command like this:

```
New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path 'C:\path\to\hardlink' -Value 'C:\path\to\original\file'
```

Of course, you could just do this with .Net namespaces:

> ['powershell [System.IO.File]'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20%5BSystem.IO.File%5D%27&t=h_&ia=web)
>
> ['powershell [System.IO.File] hardlink'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20%5BSystem.IO.File%5D%20hardlink%27&t=h_&ia=web)

```
[System.IO.File]::CreateHardLink('C:\path\to\hardlink.txt', 'C:\path\to\original.txt')
```

As documented by MS, you can run virtually any *.exe in the PS console/ISE/VSCode, as long as you pass it all it needs to execute

[PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

For example, in any of the tools mentioned above, you can still do this, even in a script:

```
fsutil hardlink create "C:\path\to\hardlink" "C:\path\to\original\file"
```

... or `mlink` as you've mentioned.

Issues around your use case using that cmdlet have been regularly discussed on SU and other forums.

> ['New-Item -ItemType HardLink'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27New-Item%20-ItemType%20HardLink%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Thanks so much, very useful info, gives me more ideas on how to do this.  I was having trouble with the iteration part, not so much with the hard link creation part.

Answer (score 1):

The following command, executed from c:\sourcedir, created in c:\destdir a hardlink to each file in c:\sourcedir:

```
gci | foreach-object {new-item -itemtype hardlink -path c:\destdir\$_ -value $_}
```

Comment: In my original post, I meant I was having trouble getting the iteration to work.  I was trying to pipe the gci output directly to new-item, without using foreach-object.  But I guess maybe new-item can't accept a collection of file objects over the pipeline input like that?  I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of that before I posted my question.  But now I'm wondering how "c:\destdir\$_" resolved the way I intended, without me needing to extract the filename only from each object coming over the pipeline.

Comment: this is a better starting point - both for single file and creating hard link for more than one file

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest an alternative.  In many cases, creating a Shortcut will do what you want.  The code to do this in powershell is on the web.
You can see one example here: https://shellgeek.com/create-shortcuts-on-user-desktop-using-powershell/

and here is their sample code  (changing the user name):

$SourceFilePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
$ShortcutPath = "C:\Users\Gary.Thomas\Desktop\MsEdge.lnk"
$WScriptObj = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$shortcut = $WscriptObj.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceFilePath
$shortcut.Save()

Answer (score 0):

`$todir=echo C:/code/AppDir/data; ls myfile.txt | %{ New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path (join-path $todir $_.Name) -Value $_ -Verbose }`

like @Jim's answer, executed from c:\sourcedir

same:
`$todir='/code/AppDir/data'; ls myfile.txt | %{ New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path (join-path $todir $_.Name) -Value $_ -Verbose }`

Comment: I find using echo is more natural than wrapping full paths in `"` nor `'` when setting string variable, as long as those paths don't contain a space.